# Bring line up to current line - VSCode shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to bring a line up to the current one?

```
true ?
  console.log('hello') :
  console.log('goodbye')
```

I.e a shortcut to bring `console.log('hello')` to be in line with `true ?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a built-in command that you can set as a shortcut:

1. Press Ctrl-K Ctrl-S to open keyboard preferences
2. Search for "join lines"
3. Hover over the "Join Lines" command and click the "+" to set a keyboard shortcut